# InvalidOperationException: Instances of abstract classes cannot be created when trying to pass image to controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to save image in my database and I am using ASP.NET MVC.
I have form that gathers data and all was working properly, before I've added image property.

This is my view code:

```
<div id="createMemberModel" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content" style="width:40%">
        <form asp-antiforgery="true" asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span class="panel-title">
                        Create new member
                    </span>
                    <span class="close glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="panel-group">
                            <labe class="control-label col-md-4">Title:</labe>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select name="Title" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option>Mr</option>
                                    <option>Mrs</option>
                                    <option>Ms</option>
                                    <option>Mx</option>
                                    <option>Miss</option>
                                    <optgroup label="Legislative and executive">
                                        <option>Representative</option>
                                        <option>Senator</option>
                                        <option>Speaker</option>
                                        <option>President</option>
                                        <option>Councillor</option>
                                        <option>Delegate</option>
                                        <option>Mayor</option>
                                        <option>Governor </option>
                                        <option>Secretary</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br /><br />
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="panel-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4">First Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input name="FirstName" class="form-control" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br /><br />
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="panel-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Last Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input name="LastName" class="form-control" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br /><br />
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="panel-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Phone Number:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input name="Phone" class="form-control" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br /><br />
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="panel-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Party:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input name="Party" class="form-control" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br /><br />
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="panel-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Email Address:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input name="Email" class="form-control" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br /><br />
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="panel-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Browse: </label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input class="form-control" id="image" name="image" type="file" hidden>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br /><br /><br />
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="panel-group pull-right">
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

So it is a simple HTML form with many properties. I have added upload button for uploading an image and started changing code in controller for Create method:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var memberRefViewModel = new CreateMemberViewModel();
    return View(memberRefViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(CreateMemberViewModel createMemberViewModel, HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    if (image != null)
    {
        createMemberViewModel.Image = new byte[image.ContentLength];
        image.InputStream.Read(createMemberViewModel.Image, 0, image.ContentLength);
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //TODO ADD TRY CATCH
        MemberEntity mem = Mapper.Map<MemberEntity>(createMemberViewModel);
        var tenantId = sessionHelper.GetTenantIdFromSession().Value;
        TenantEntity t = this.tenantService.Get(tenantId);
        mem.Tenant = t;
        mem.IsActive = true;
        this.service.Add(mem);

        this.gcmService.SendGCMNotification("New member has been created.");

        return RedirectToAction("Index").WithSuccess($"{createMemberViewModel.Title} {createMemberViewModel.FirstName} {createMemberViewModel.LastName} created successfully.");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(createMemberViewModel).WithError("Create not valid. Please check fields are valid.");
    }
}
```

I've added HttpPostedFileBase and I am trying to check if image is null or not. The moment I did this I've started getting exception saying:

```
InvalidOperationException: Instances of abstract classes cannot be created.
```

Which I totally get it, but I don't understand what is causing the problem here?

My first thought was that this has something to do with Automapper which I use. I was thinking that maybe bindings are not good or something like that, but after adding bindings in model I still have the same.

Problem occurs the same second I click Create button and it never hits backend code brake-points. So I guess I am missing something on that view?

If it means anything these are raw exception details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Instances of abstract classes cannot be created.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IRuntimeMethodInfo method)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType, Object target)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.CreateDelegate()
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda, DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.CreateModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.<BindModelCoreAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultControllerArgumentBinder.<BindModelAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultControllerArgumentBinder.<BindArgumentsCoreAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAllActionFiltersAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeExceptionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ExceptionTrackingMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<ExecuteWithFilter>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
```

This is my model:

```
public class CreateMemberViewModel : IMapFrom<MemberEntity>, IMapTo<MemberEntity>, IHaveCustomMappings
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Party { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get { return $"{Title} {FirstName} {LastName}"; } }

    public void CreateMappings(IMapperConfigurationExpression configuration)
    {
        configuration.CreateMap<CreateMemberViewModel, MemberEntity>()
            .ForMember(t => t.Image, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(t => t.Image == null ? null : t.Image));
    }
}
```

I was pretty sure that in the old MVC this could work, but how to make it work in ASP.NET Core? Anybody has an idea what is wrong with this?

Comment: Can you please share `CreateMemberViewModel`? You might have some abstract type reference in it and the model binder tries to create an instance of that type

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci I will update my question with model right away.